# MySQL CHECK constraint to ensure record does not refer to itself with autoincrement id?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have a SQL table that can reference another record in the table as its `parent` but should not reference itself. I have attempted to enforce this with a `CHECK` constraint but my attempts have failed as the `id` is an auto-increment column. Is there any other way to ensure that `parent_id <> id`?

My current attempt, which fails with error `Check constraint 'not_own_parent' cannot refer to an auto-increment column. (errno 3818)`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `content` (
    `id` serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    `item_id` int NOT NULL,
    `nested_item_id` int,
    `block_id` int,
    `order` int NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT not_own_parent CHECK (nested_item_id <> id)
);
```

Comment: Maybe you can perform tha check in a post-insert trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo of using a trigger to cancel an insert that violates the condition you describe. You must use an AFTER trigger because in a BEFORE trigger the auto-increment value has not yet been generated.

```
mysql> delimiter ;;
mysql> create trigger t after insert on content
    -> for each row begin
    -> if NEW.nested_item_id = NEW.id then
    -> signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'content cannot reference itself';
    -> end if;
    -> end;;
mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> insert into content set item_id = 1, nested_item_id = 1, `order` = 1;
ERROR 1644 (45000): content cannot reference itself

mysql> insert into content set item_id = 1, nested_item_id = 2, `order` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, that's helpful. Hadn't considered a trigger, but this will enforce the consistency at the database level, which is what I was trying to do (noting that the answer from @o-jones also has merit).

Answer (score 1):

Don't put this kind of thing in a constraint. For one thing, you can't do it directly in MySql.  You'd have to use a trigger or something.

Instead:

1. write your CRUD code carefully, so it avoids generating incorrect rows. You have to do that anyway.
2. write a little program called "database_consistent" or something. Have it run a bunch of queries looking for any errors like the one you're trying to avoid. Have it send emails or SMSs if it finds problems.  Run it often during development and at least daily in production.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping there was some way I'd missed to enforce this in the database but makes sense to check for consistency in some other way (particularly as I can't enforce foreign key constraints in MySQL either, so can check referential integrity at the same time).

Comment: Exactly. Your database consistency tool deserves some serious care if your app is live on a large scale.

Answer (score -1):

One way to control auto-generated live values is by using triggers to manage new values.

For example, create instead of insert trigger to control newly generated ID. In triggers, you can make decisions based on the new value.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).